# How to use special character in jQuery array

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, scala, playframework

I am getting an error "Statement Expected", while I need to fetch data from mysql to text field.

I am trying to make text field search auto complete. Please help me or provide  me another way to do search autocomplete in play framework.

```
@( formList: List[Driver_registrationInfo],form: 
 Form[Driver_registrationInfo]) )
@main_dashboard("Vehicle tracker ") {
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="automplete-1" name="object.name"  
/>
@for(info <- Driver_registrationInfo.findAll()) {

    <script>

    <!-- Javascript -->
    $ ( function ( ) {
    var availableTutorials =[

       "@info.names"

    ] ;
    $ ( "#automplete-1" ).autocomplete ( {
    minLength : 2,
    source : availableTutorials
    } ) ;
    } ) ;
    </script>

}
```

Comment: You can not use HTML comments `<!-- Javascript -->` inside script tags.

Comment: I removed comments but still i get an error statement expected

Comment: I don't know playframework, but I can see you have unmatched `()` in the second line and unmatched `{}` in the third line. The error `Statement Expected` is showing in the browser console?

Comment: They match on 9th and 10th line